# Running command via su as www-data user fails silently

Tags: bash, su

I am trying to run a daemonised webserver as www-data user but I have reduced the problem down to the fact I can't even run the simplest of commands using `su`.

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 22 11:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 22 11:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    0 Apr 22 11:39 hello.txt
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# sudo -u www-data 'ls'
hello.txt
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# su - www-data -c "ls"
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# echo $?  # Unknown problem as no error text to stout from previous command
1
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# su -c "ls" www-data
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# echo $?  # Unknown problem as no error text to stout from previous command
1
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# su -c "ls" root
hello.txt
root@ubuntu:/var/www/hello# su --help
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd
```

Two questions:

1. How to get better error messages from `su`
2. How to fix the fundamental problem of the command erroring when run as www-data user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*su* runs the given command indirectly – it calls the target user's **default shell** (the 7th "login shell" field in /etc/passwd) with the `-c`, `<command>` parameters. For example, when you run `su root -c "foo"`, it ends up running `/bin/sh -c "foo"` or similar.

However, service accounts (which aren't meant for interactive use) traditionally have a dummy shell configured, such as /bin/false or /sbin/nologin. (The former does nothing at all; the latter prints a message such as "This account is not available".)

*(To find out what a user's default shell is, run `getent passwd www-data` and look at the last field.)*

So in your case, *su* runs `/bin/false -c "foo"` or `/sbin/nologin -c "foo"`, and nothing useful happens.

There is no error message because this behavior is not actually an error: su does precisely what it is configured to do, as does the so-called "shell" configured for this account. However, you can see more under-the-hood details by running `strace -fe execve -- su www-data -c "foo"` (you must be root to do this).

---

Actual services do not have this problem because they generally *do not use* the login-shell anywhere in the startup process. The service manager simply executes the daemon program directly. (In fact, you really should use a service manager. Most systems come with systemd, upstart, or at least 'start-stop-daemon'. *su* is not meant to run daemons at all.)

If you really *must* use `su www-data` to do something, then its --help output shows the necessary option:

```
-s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd
```

Use this option to specify a "normal" shell, for example:

```
su www-data -s /bin/sh -c "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `su`, what is passed to the shell is the first argument after `-c`, not all arguments that follow it. So

```
su www-data -c ls foo
```

Executes `ls`  and not `ls foo`. If you want to execute a command with arguments, include everything in quotes to make it a single argument:

```
su www-data -c "ls foo"
```

Then you will be executing `ls` with real arguments, and will see real messages.